# Sharing custom fields across TFS 2015 Update 1 work items

Tags: tfs-2015

I am working adding some customization to TFS 2015 Update 1 work item templates. I have started with the bug template and have successfully mirrored that across multiple projects.

I now have to make changes to the feature template, those changes need to include fields of the same name due to queries that will be filtering on values in the custom field.

I am finding that I cannot resuse the custom fields from the bug in the feature template. I also cannot create a custom field for the feature template with the same name as that in the bug.

Is there anyway to do this? My custom field in the bug is named "Task Status" with a ref name of .task.status.

Is there any way of making this existing custom field usable across template types? My end users don't want to have to duplicate queries to obtain the same data from multiple work item types.

Thanks!

Comment: What error message did you receive when save the customized feature template with "Task Status"?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue at my side, list my steps for your reference (I'm doing it from [TFS Power Tools\Process Template Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)):

1. Add "TaskStatus" field for Bug and save it:
   [image]
2. Add "TaskStatus" field for Feature and save it(The setting is the same):
   [image]

Then I just need one query for both Bug and Feature work items:
[image]

Comment: I have an ALLOWEDVALUES rule on a custom field in WIT #1. Is there any way I share this list with the instance of the custom field in WIT #2? I don't want to have to maintain 2 lists.